# Detect event in cordova webView

Tags: android, cordova, events, webview, payment

I have a `cordova` App with `ONSEN` framework, and have created a module to connect to a payment gateway, all works well creating a `webview` to navigate to payment page, when transaction is successful I return to previous app page  giving tap in mobile back button, the issue is that I can't get event to inform user that payment has been successful.
I have tried "**postpop**" event but it does not work.
regards